# Is there some kind of list with special (memory) addresses for Linux or gcc?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, gcc

I've heard there are some special addresses(or, at lease, some ranges with special addresses), used from Linux(or gcc, I don't know and this is a part of the question), but I can't find such. And I don't even know how to look for it.

( for example, in Visual Studio, there's such thing for uninitialized variables )

And this question was "introduced" by the more specific one (and it doesn't deserve to be a separate question, that's why I'll ask it here): is 0x30303030 some special address or something?

Because I have a backtrace like:

```
#0  0x003fa527 in memset () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x4e5fffa0 in ?? ()
#2  0x00787d13 in std::num_put > >::_M_group_int () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0079a1e4 in std::operator, std::allocator > () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x30303030 in ?? ()
#5  0x30303030 in ?? ()

...
#1483 0x30303030 in ?? ()
#1484 0x30303030 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0xb3927000
```

And this have 1400+ lines like `0x30303030 in ?? ()`

Does this mean something, or it's just a random memory address and it looks like a bottomless recursion? The problem is, that I cannot reproduce it, so debugging or using valgrind becomes useless :\

I know, that this is awful question with no any useful information, but I decided to give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASCII it's "0000", so it may be that something got overrun. Or that there's a memory error somewhere.

Comment: I know, that it's "0000", but aren't all these hex numbers memory addresses? Ir they are and "0000" is some special address? And what would "memory error" mean?

Comment: Memory addresses are just sequences of bytes, the same as any other bytes. And "memory error" means pretty much what it says on the box: a physical error in a memory module.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually used by the debugger to mark uninitialized pointers. The addresses themselves are irrelevant and are not special in any way. Such a thing may not exist under GCC, depends on how they chose to write their debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing memset at the top of the backtrace, there are high odds that it didn't set the exact memory area you expected. Perhaps a bit too much was set to '0'?

Comment: I don't know, I don't even know where the problem started (it's thousands of lines application, multithreaded; and the core says nothing..) Also, we don't use such (c)function, the app is written on C++, so I guess it's something to do with some `std::string` or I don't know :\ It's very strange and I don't see anything, that can help me reproduce, isolate or locate the problem